# PHPMailer failing with ssl

Tags: email, ssl, phpmailer, exim4

I'm having troubles sending an email with PHPMailer through my SMTP which is ssl enabled.

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
// HTML email!
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
//Ask for HTML-friendly debug output
$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';
//Set the hostname of the mail server
$mail->Host = "server.co.tz";
//Set the SMTP port number - likely to be 25, 465 or 587
$mail->Port = 465;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
//Username to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Username = "xxxxxxx";
//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "yyyyyyy";
```

When i run the script I get the following error:

```
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed.
```

And on the exim4 logs:

```
2016-02-24 11:02:20 TLS error on connection from [197.215.254.114] (gnutls_handshake): A TLS fatal alert has been received.
```

I have no clue on what is going wrong here.

I use the SMTP regurarly for my email clients and the SSL certificate is a valid one.

Update:

Got latest version and set debug to 3 but still no luck:

```
Connection: opening to ssl://fsm.co.tz:465, timeout=300, options=array ()
SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0)
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

Comment: How about turning debug output on? `SMTPDebug = 3` should be enough.

Comment: It looks like you're running an old version of PHPMailer too, so [get the latest](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer).

Answer (score 0):

As of today @PHPMailer version 6.1.4
These worked for me:-

```
    $email->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER; 
    $email->isSMTP(); 
    $email->Host       = 'host';
    $email->SMTPAuth   = true; 
    $email->Username   = 'username';  
    $email->Password   = 'password'; 
    $email->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS;
    $email->Port       = 465;
```

Answer (score -2):

The solution is to add the following to the configuration:

```
$mail->SMTPOptions = array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
        'allow_self_signed' => false
    )
);
```

Comment: It's not really a solution, but a (temporary) workaround. Nevertheless, this is "correct" in that it can get you up-and-running quickly while testing with self-signed or otherwise bad certificates.

If this works, the "proper" solution is to get a proper certificate for your mail server.